How high should the stone edging be around a flower bed? One landscaper said the height of the stone border should be below weep holes on the house
I've been shopping landscapers to install stone edging around a small flower bed. Every other company has recommended two 4-inch rows of stone (which matches my preference). One landscaper recommended one 4-inch row. He said the height of the border should not exceed the foundation because water could get in the weep holes and damage the foundation.
I've not heard this from anyone else or seen this online anywhere. Is this a real concern? What do you think?


I'm no expert here but https://theconstructor.org/structures/weep-holes-retaining-walls-types-functions-need/17049/ is a useful read.  I posit if you have weep holes you don't want to block them.

If you want the stone edging to be 8 inches high, were you intending to fill it with soil to raise the soil height of the bed?

I had a personal experience with this. The previous owners of a house I no longer own had the dirt in the bed built up above the weep holes. We had ants coming into our house due to this. I removed 6” of dirt from the bed and the issue was resolved.

The weep holes are required by many building standards because they allow any moisture that gets behind the permeable brick wall to exit at the bottom. Given the impermeable vapor barrier behind the brick wall the weeping holes are the only way for moisture to exit the building envelope.
If they are covered you take your chances that mold, mildew and other undesirables can grow between the brick and the vapor barrier.
So the weeping holes should not be covered but you can still put two rows of stone by the walkway as long as you do not fill the bed too high.

It depends. If its on a slope and water isnt going to  pool, then it doesnt matter. Otherwise go with cuation, and keep them below the weepholes.
